# Possible bug with Scala 2.10.2 implicits

Tags: scala, implicit

I'm getting unexpected behavior with Scala implicit resolution, and I'd like to know whether the bug is in my understanding or in the Scala compiler.
Here's the code:

```scala
trait Trait1[A]

implicit def trait1ToList[A](trait1: Trait1[A]): List[A] = ???

trait Trait2[C]

{
  implicit def trait2Implicit[A, C <% List[A]]: Trait2[C] = ???

  // Compiles, as expected.
  implicitly[Trait2[Trait1[Int]]]
}

{
  implicit def trait2Pimp[A, C <% List[A]](int: Int): Trait2[C] = ???

  // Compiles, as expected.
  implicitly[Int => Trait2[Trait1[Int]]]

  // Does not compile, which is unexpected.
  // This is weird, because the fact the previous line compiles
  // implies the implicit conversion is in scope.
  2: Trait2[Trait1[Int]]
}
```

The compilation error is:

```
[error] /Users/eric/Dropbox/t/2013_q1/billy/src/test/scala/billy/experiments/wideBaseline/testWideBaselineExperiment.scala:56: No implicit view available from Trait1[Int] => List[A].
[error]       2: Trait2[Trait1[Int]]
[error]       ^
```

Comment: Note that the error goes away if you write `implicit val conv = implicitly[Int => Trait2[Trait1[Int]]]`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9138312/1296806, I presume.

Comment: So this bug is more than 3 years old. Great... BTW, make that link an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this was a [bug](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-3346) in the scala compiler that has since been fixed in 2.11.